# Get rid of the number of documents icon in VS Code

Tags: macos, mac, text-editors, visual-studio-code

I'd like to remove the icon which shows the number of unsaved files in Explorer.

I'm on the most up to date version on the most up to date Mac.

I went through the settings and couldn't find the relevant one.

[image: icon]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there any good solutions for you problem. I suggest to options:

1. Set auto saving for your files
2. Make all badges transparent

   ```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "activityBarBadge.background": "#0000",
        "activityBarBadge.foreground": "#0000",
    }
   ```